# What is the policy on flag review?

Tags: discussion, flagging

If not deemed helpful flags can be declined or disputed. What flags should be declined and what flags should be disputed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your flag is dismissed by somebody, it might be for one of several reasons:

This list is incomplete of course

- You could have simply misunderstood a post. For example, an answer might not *seem* to answer the question, but it does if read it more carefully
- A seemingly duplicate question might have merit if the differences are subtle but important (think Python 3 questions, or Compiz vs Mutter)
- The reviewer took care of the post in some other way. E.g. a down-vote instead of deleting the post, where the flag indicates something unnecessary
- The user invalidated your objection by improving their post

---

If you object to a reviewers decision, you can always just leave a message to one of the moderators, and/or start a discussion about the disputed post in the chat room.

We use our best judgement when approving or declining flags. If you disagree, help us do a better job by discussing the flag specifically.

Comment: This makes sense. I'm trying to understand so that I can flag better and to make moderator's lives easier. You write "If you object to a reviewers decision, you can always just leave a message to one of the moderators", do you mean leaving a message by flagging?

Comment: No, I was thinking about the [Ask Ubuntu Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the privilege pages:

- https://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts
- https://askubuntu.com/privileges/moderator-tools

It's pretty straight forward, the scope of the site is listed in the FAQ so it's not like we're making judgement calls all the time.

Though every once in a while I might mark a flag as invalid when someone flags an answer that might be not-very-high-quality but isn't so bad that it should be deleted. In those cases IMO it should just be a downvote. I usually decline the flag and then read the answer and it usually just needs a down vote.

Comment: I understand that there's not much time to judge every flag. The reason I ask is that I got some declined flags which I didn't understand or agree to, so I'm wondering about the meaning of flag judgements so that I may flag more correctly.

Comment: @N.N. Yeah it would be nice if we could put a decline reason in there.

Comment: Indeed. I've added a feature request, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/add-option-to-add-reason-for-disputing-or-declining-a-flag